# How to plot pie chart in R from a table with relative Frequency?

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart, frequency

I am brand new to R. I need to plot a pie graph. Now I have tried my best but it's not generating a pie chart for me. Below is my code.

```
socialIssue <- matrix(c(245,112,153,71,133,306),ncol=1,byrow=T)
rownames(socialIssue) <- c("Housing","Transportation","Health Care","Education","Food","Other")
colnames(socialIssue) <- c("Frequency")
socialIssue <- as.table(socialIssue)
socialIssue/sum(socialIssue)

cols <- rainbow(nrow(socialIssue))
pie(socialIssue$Frequency, labels=paste0(round(socialIssue$Frequency/sum(socialIssue$Frequency)*100,2),"%"),colnames=cols)
```

This is the following output. The frequency outputted is correct.

```
socialIssue <- matrix(c(245,112,153,71,133,306),ncol=1,byrow=T)
> rownames(socialIssue) <- c("Housing","Transportation","Health Care","Education","Food","Other")
> colnames(socialIssue) <- c("Frequency")
> socialIssue <- as.table(socialIssue)
> socialIssue/sum(socialIssue)
                Frequency
Housing        0.24019608
Transportation 0.10980392
Health Care    0.15000000
Education      0.06960784
Food           0.13039216
Other          0.30000000
> 
> cols <- rainbow(nrow(socialIssue))
> pie(socialIssue$Frequency, labels=paste0(round(socialIssue$Frequency/sum(socialIssue$Frequency)*100,2),"%"),colnames=cols)
Error in socialIssue$Frequency : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to dataframe and then plot

```
socialIssue = as.data.frame(socialIssue)
socialIssue$percent = round(100*socialIssue$Freq/sum(socialIssue$Freq), digits = 1)
socialIssue$label = paste(socialIssue$Var1," (", socialIssue$percent,"%)", sep = "")
pie(socialIssue$Freq, labels = socialIssue$label, col = cols)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
pie(socialIssue[, 1],
    labels = paste0(round(socialIssue[, 1] / sum(socialIssue[, 1]) * 100, 2), "%"))
```

Because you have a matrix, not a data frame.

Comment: thank you...but is there any way I can write the title of my graph and also show the legend at the bottom. The legend should state the categories and the percentage should be displayed on the pie chart.

Answer (score 2):

`prop.table` takes care of the `%` calculation - `sprintf` deals with the formatting of the number values so you have consistent decimal places.

All of the conversion code isn't required either:

```
socialIssue <- matrix(c(245,112,153,71,133,306),ncol=1,byrow=T)
pie(socialIssue, labels=sprintf("%.2f%%", prop.table(socialIssue)*100))
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R, with the colors you used (the param name should be `cols` instead of `colnames'), with legends added:

```
pie(socialIssue[,1], labels=paste0(round(socialIssue/sum(socialIssue)*100,2),"%"),col=cols)
legend('bottomright', legend=rownames(socialIssue), fill=cols, bty='n')
```

[image]

or with `ggplot2`

```
socialIssue <- matrix(c(245,112,153,71,133,306),ncol=1,byrow=T)
rownames(socialIssue) <- c("Housing","Transportation","Health Care","Education","Food","Other")
colnames(socialIssue) <- c("Frequency")
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(as.data.frame(socialIssue), aes(x='',y=Frequency, fill=as.factor(Frequency))) + 
  geom_bar(width=1, stat='identity')  +   
  scale_fill_manual(values=cols, labels=rownames(socialIssue)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y") + theme_bw()
```

[image]